# How to find items tied for most appearances in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create a list of the items in list `w` tied for appearing the most times in `w`.  In other words, if 22 appears in `w` more than any other number, I want the result to be `{22}`.  If 34 and 55 appear the most times in `w` but the same number of times, I want the result to be `{34,55}`.

The example below just uses a randomly generated list `w`.  My method works but is ugly and inefficient.

```
w = RandomInteger[100, 200]
fw = w // DeleteDuplicates
wc = Counts[w]
m = Max[fw /. wc]
Reap[Do[If[(fw[[i]] /. wc) == m, Sow[fw[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[fw]}]][[2, 1]]
```

Is there a tidier way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [`Commonest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Commonest.html):

```
SeedRandom[1]
w = RandomInteger[100, 200];

Commonest[w]
```

> {68, 25, 63}

```
% /. Counts[w]
```

> {5, 5, 5}

Comment: Thank you!  The first part is exactly what I need.  But you could explain how the syntax of the second part works?  I don't even know how to look that up.

Comment: @JerryGuern, thank you for the accept. About the last line: it  gives the same result as `{68, 25, 63} /. Counts[w]`.  `%`  stands for _the last result generated_ . (See  [Out (%)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Out.html) in the docs.)  So the last line is the same as `Count[w, #]&/@ {68,25,63}`. See also:  [Map (/@)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html), [Function (&)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) and [Slot (#)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the followup and links.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];

list = RandomInteger[100, 200];
```

Using `Counts`

```
c = Counts @ list;
```

Visualization

```
Histogram[c, LabelingFunction -> Above]
```

[image]

Using `MaximalBy`

```
MaximalBy[c, # &]
```

<|68 -> 5, 25 -> 5, 63 -> 5|>

```
Keys[%]
```

{68, 25, 63}

Using `Select` to see more than one bin

```
Select[c, MatchQ[4 | 5]] // ReverseSort
```

returns

```
<|63 -> 5, 25 -> 5, 68 -> 5, 
  35 -> 4, 16 -> 4, 55 -> 4, 41 -> 4, 6 -> 4, 45 -> 4, 17 -> 4, 76 -> 4, 100 -> 4|>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];

list = RandomInteger[100, 200];
```

Using `Gather`, `Pick` and `Max`:

```
c = Map[Function[x, Splice@{x[[1]] -> Length@x}], Gather[list]][[All, 2]];

Pick[First /@ Gather[list], Thread[c == Max@c]]

(*{68, 25, 63}*)

% /. Counts[list]

(*{5, 5, 5}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Tally` and `GroupBy`:**

```
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[100, 200];
GroupBy[Tally@list, Last] // Last
```

> {{68, 5}, {25, 5}, {63, 5}}